# How many one to one functions?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

how many one to one functions for $$p : (4, 5, . . . , 8) \to (4, 5, . . . , 8)$$ if:

$p(6) = 6$. What about $p(6) \neq 6$?

I thought 1 was 4! and 2 was $4*4!$, but that doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly the answer to $(1)$ is $4!=24$.

The total number of one-to-one functions is $5!=120$.

The total number of one-to-one functions minus the number of one-to-one functions that have $6$ as a fixed point will be the number of one-to-one functions that do not have $6$ as a fixed point.

Probably the reasoning that led you to the conclusion that it's $4\times 4! = 4\times 24$ is correct.

Comment: 5! - 4! is equilvelent to 4 * 4!, correct? when i put that answer into the answer box, it says it is incorrect. *edit* there was an error with the answer key having the incorrect answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: @shanmalik Yes, the two are equal. But it's possible that the system you're using doesn't view them as such, for example, if the answer is hard coded into it.